# KOMA-Script scrbook: How to remove period after part

Tags: punctuation, koma-script, scrbook

I'm using `scrbook` to typeset a document and I'm using `\part` for formatting the parts of it.

The default output renders `\part{Mytitle}` into

> Part I.
>
> Mytitle

Now I'd like to get rid of the period after "Part I." In the KOMA-Script guide I have only found options to generally switch off punctuation after every part, chapter, section etc.

So I tried `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}}` but this strangely still puts a period after the roman number. However, `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}` and `\renewcommand{\thepart}{\arabic{part}.}` produce the expected difference.

So what is so special with roman numbering here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not automatic solution to this, but it is not hard to redefine the format of the part headings.  The default is

```
\newcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart\autodot}
```

you just need to redefine this removing the `\autodot`.

[image: Part sample]

[image: Chapter/section sample]

```
\documentclass[numbers=enddot]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart}

\begin{document}
\part{My part}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
\part{My part}
\chapter{My chapter}
\section{My section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. I think this is the simplest/shortest solution. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 18):

KOMA-Script decides in the default setting that an “end dot” will be used if any section numbering macros (`\thepart`, `\thechapter`, …) use Roman numbers or any letters.

When you change `\thepart` to use `\arabic`, it will switch automaticaly to “no end dot”.

Do you want

- to never have an end dot, or
- to not have an end dot with Roman part numbers?

### No end dot in any numbers

You can use the `numbers` class option with the value `noenddot`.
See

- page 94 of the [German KOMA-Script manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguide.pdf), Tabelle 3.14, or
- page 84 of the [English KOMA-Scrip manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/koma-script/scrguien.pdf), Table 3.14.

#### Code

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\part{Mytitle}
\chapter{My other title with no end dot}
\end{document}
```

### No end dot in the part number

If you only want the part’s number to not be followed by a dot but all other section numbers followed by one, KOMA-Script does not provide an interface for that.

My proposal:

Use the default setting for `numbers` (i.e. `auto`; because `\thepart` still uses `\Roman` all other section numbers will get the dot either way) and just overwrite `\partformat`:

```
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart}
%\newcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart\autodot}% <- original defintion in scrbook.cls
```

This will remove `\autodot` from the definition.

#### Code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\partname~\thepart}
\begin{document}
\part{Mytitle}
\chapter{My other title with an end dot}
\end{document}
```

### Output (both)

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to limit this to the end dot after parts (so that chapters would still get an end dot)?

Comment: @Jake I don't think that there's an automatic solution for this. But it shouldn't be that complicated to get this done.

Comment: @Jake See my updated answer. As Benedikt Bauer already said: There's no interface for that. I think this is the easiest solution. As far as I can see, `\partformat` will not be redefined by KOMA-Script anywhere, so it should be safe.