# How to remove period after part number in TOC (KOMA used)

Tags: formatting, koma-script, parts

How to remove period after part number in TOC (KOMA used)?
My solution was to set `tocloft` package, which is provide command `\cftpartaftersnum` but I do not want to use it for some compatibility reasons.
[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{%
  \figurename~\thefigure%
%  \autodot% DELETED
}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{One}
\part{Two}
\end{document}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [KOMA-Script scrbook: How to remove period after part](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102303/koma-script-scrbook-how-to-remove-period-after-part)

Comment: @PierPaolo This is different problem. The suppressing period in toc and in mainmatter are independent. As you can see in my MWE period after part number are suppressed in mainmatter.

Comment: If the change is meant for all sectioning levels, add `\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\numberline@numberformat}[1]{\ifstr{#1}{}{}{#1}}\makeatother` in the preamble.

Comment: @karlkoeller Yes, this is the solution. Can you, please, add the comment as answer.

Comment: @sergiokapone Did you want that behavior *all over the document*, not only in the ToC?

Comment: @karlkoeller Only for TOC. And it is good, that it can be made independently for TOC and mainmatter.

Comment: You know that the reader is searching for nunmbers and `1.` is different from `1`? This might lead to confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the dots for all sectioning levels, write the following lines in your preamble

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\numberline@numberformat}[1]{\ifstr{#1}{}{}{#1}}
\ma‌​keatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setmainlanguage{ukrainian}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{%
  \figurename~\thefigure%
%  \autodot% DELETED
}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\numberline@numberformat}[1]{\ifstr{#1}{}{}{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{One}
\chapter{First}
\part{Two}
\chapter{Second}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update**

To remove the dots at the end of the numbers only in TOC and lists you can use

```
\BeforeStartingTOC{\def\autodot{}}
```

If this should be done only for TOC (or for a special) list you can add the optional argument

```
\BeforeStartingTOC[toc]{\def\autodot{}}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\BeforeStartingTOC{\def\autodot{}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\part{Two}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

You could use the KOMA-Script class option `numbers=noenddot` to suppress the end dots for all sectioning levels (and figures etc.) in mainmatter *and* TOC:

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\part{Two}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the OP wants this behavior only in the ToC.

Comment: From his comment to the question: "As you can see in my MWE period after part number are suppressed in mainmatter." So I think he removes the dot not only for the figures but also for the parts in the mainmatter.