# How to remove period after final number on the titles of the scrbook class in spanish?

Tags: babel, scrbook, spanish

This question is almost a duplicate of this [one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223798/how-to-remove-period-after-part-number-in-toc-koma-used).
Except the answer does not work for the spanish language.

You can check by commenting/removing the 2nd and 3rd lines.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\def\spanishoptions{mexico}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\part{Two}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure that the heading numbers will be controlled by the KOMA-Script class use the babel option `es-nosectiondot`.

```
\documentclass[numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\def\spanishoptions{mexico}
\usepackage[
  spanish,
  es-nosectiondot% <- added
]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{One}
\part{Two}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]