# When using \part, unwanted full stop/period appears after float numbers in scrbook

Tags: floats, numbering, koma-script, punctuation, scrbook

I'm writing a document using the `scrbook` class, and I'm having some strange behavior when combing floats with the `\part` macro.

For the following document:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\part{A Part} % This line seems to be creating the problem. If you comment it out, you'll notice that the extra "." character disappears.

\chapter{A Chapter}

\section{A Section}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \textit{The contents of the figure go here.}
    \caption{A Figure.}
    \label{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would expect the output to look something like this:

[image: Page with contents: "1 A Chapter [newline] 1.1 A Section [at bottom of page] The contents of the figure go here. [newline] Figure 1.1: A Figure.]

Instead, it looks like this:

[image: Page with contents: "1. A Chapter [newline] 1.1. A Section [at bottom of page] The contents of the figure go here. [newline] Figure 1.1.: A Figure.]

The difference is very subtle, but there is a period after the name of the figure and before the colon, which looks odd:

[image: Figure 1.1.: A Figure.]

**How can this period be removed?**

Comment: I linked to that in my answer to this question—it's the same solution, but for a different problem. I wrote this question and answer because I wanted people to be able to find it in case they had the same problem. I'm also wondering if it's possible to remove *just* the extra period after "Figure 1.1." without changing the rest of the section titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [KOMA-Script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf):

> According to DUDEN, if only Arabic numerals are used to number section headings, the German practice is to have no point at the end (see [DUD96, R 3]). On the other hand, if Roman numerals or letters appear in the numbering, then a point should appear at the end of the numbering (see [DUD96, R 4]). KOMA-Script has a mechanism that tries to automate this somewhat complex rule.

Unfortunately, as of 2023, it appears that the KOMA-Script book class also applies this convention *everywhere* if Roman numerals are used *anywhere* in the document. The part created by `\part{A Part}` uses a Roman numeral in the example above, so periods appear after all automatic section/float numbers in the rest of the document. To fix this, you can explicitly disable the automatic application of this convention by loading the KOMA-Script book class with the `numbers=noendperiod` option:

```latex
\documentclass[numbers=noendperiod]{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\part{A Part}

\chapter{A Chapter}

\section{A Section}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \textit{The contents of the figure go here.}
    \caption{A Figure.}
    \label{Test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This produces an output without the additional period.

---

A related (but non-duplicate) question may be viewed at: [KOMA-Script scrbook: How to remove period after part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102303)

Comment: Not everywhere, but in the number of any section level (part … subparagraph) and derived numbers. And because `figure` numbers depend on chapter numbers they also depend on the feature. BTW: Analog to the `\partformat` in some answers to the referred question, there are also `\figureformat` and `\tableformat`.